# How to use ExpressionBuilder in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, expressionbuilder

Does MVC3 Razor Supports ExpressionBuilder ?

Can anyone provide sample how to use ExpressionBuilder with MVC3 Razor application.

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not supported, it is built for web controls. Which are a part of WebForms.